# Python RegEx Woes

Tags: python, regex

I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
import re
import csv

def check(q, s):
  match = re.search(r'%s' % q, s, re.IGNORECASE)
  if match:
    return True
  else:
    return False

tstr = []

# test strings
tstr.append('testthisisnotworking')
tstr.append('This is a TEsT')
tstr.append('This is a    TEST    mon!')

f = open('testwords.txt', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for type, term, exp in reader:
  for i in range(2):
    if check(exp, tstr[i]):
      print exp + " hit on " + tstr[i]
    else:
      print exp + " did NOT hit on " + tstr[i]
f.close()
```

testwords.txt contains this line:

```
blah, blah, test
```

So essentially 'test' is the RegEx pattern. Nothing complex, just a simple word. Here's the output:

```
test did NOT hit on testthisisnotworking
test hit on This is a TEsT
test hit on This is a    TEST    mon!
```

Why does it NOT hit on the first string? I also tried `\s*test\s*` with no luck. Help?

Comment: I don't know python that well but I know regexes. Can you narrow it down to just a potential problem of the regex? http://worksol.be/regex.html

Comment: "Python regex woes". That gave me a small chuckle. I feel you, regexes can be woeful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `print repr(exp)` to the top of the first `for` loop shows that `exp` is `' test'`, note the leading space.

This isn't that surprising since `csv.reader()` splits on commas, try changing your code to the following:

```
for type, term, exp in reader:
  exp = exp.strip()
  for s in tstr:
    if check(exp, s):
      print exp + " hit on " + s
    else:
      print exp + " did NOT hit on " + s
```

Note that in addition to the `strip()` call which will remove the leading a trailing whitespace, I change your second for loop to just loop directly over the strings in `tstr` instead of over a range.  There was actually a bug in your current code because `tstr` contained three values but you only checked the first two because `for i in range(2)` will only give you `i=0` and `i=1`.

Answer (score 6):

The `csv` module by default returns blank spaces around words in the input (this can be changed by using a different "dialect"). So `exp` contains `" test"` with a leading space.

A quick way to fix this would be to add:

```
exp = exp.strip()
```

after you read from the CSV file.

Comment: `strip` has been a good friend to avoid surprises in cases like this. I'd say it is good practice to always use it (doesn't hurt anyway)